# How do you extract the information of a 2D array stored as one element within an ArrayList? Is it even possible?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This question has been completely re-evaluated, sorry for the old one you guys answered sometime back.

The real problem I am having is not storing a 2D element into an Arraylist, the problem is more like how can you extract the information of a 2D array element within the Arraylist its stored in. Also ignore DataHandler.init() for those who were here a long time back.

Code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
    sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
    new FileReader(xFileLocation.get(x))));

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        Line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] InArray = Line.split(",");

        for (int t = 0; t < InArray.length; t++) {
            Data[RowC][t] = InArray[t];
        }

        RowC++;
        DataHandler.init(Data); 
    }

    storeID.add(Data[0][1]);

    for (int z = 21; z < Data.length; z++) {
        storeTemp.add(Data[z][7]);
        storePrec.add(Data[z][17]);
        storeSnow.add(Data[z][15]);
        storeWind.add(Data[z][25]);
    }

    setID.add(storeID.get(x));
    setTemp.add(storeTemp.get(x));
    setPrec.add(storePrec.get(x));
    setSnow.add(storeSnow.get(x));
    setWind.add(storeWind.get(x));

}
```

Comment: What? This looks like legit English, but it doesn't make much sense, unfortunately. Can you make an SSCCE?

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your snippet where the null value occurs. Does it throw a NullPointerException? Can you post a stack trace? What is `x` in `setID.add(storeID.get(x));`?

Comment: What are your data and what do you expect? Please add your variable declarations and a bit more code (what values are you using for `x` mainly)

Comment: What does DataHandler.init() do?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion before, the question I asked was a dumb one, I meant to ask this one. FYI ignore the DataHandler.init()

Comment: removed my answer, meaningless after OP edit... but I still don't understand what you want to do. I guess it would be easier if you could provide us some context: original data format (you CSV structure), and what is the point of your whole code. Is it about extracting meteorological data from a CSV to some data structure? What is the final expected data format?